# Python error "I/O operation on closed file" when using a file handle with thread lock

Tags: python, multithreading, file, io

I am trying to write to one file using Python `threading` module and I am already using the lock to access the file. the class like below:

```
  class WriteToFile(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self,lock,fp):
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)
          self.lock=lock
          self.fp=fp
      def run():
          self.lock.acquire()
          self.fp.write('some string')
          self.lock.release()
  f=open('somefile','a')
  lock=threading.Lock()
  thread= WriteToFile(lock,f)
  thread.start()
```

Above code could only keep running for some time, and stoped due to `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

But if I access the file between the 'lock acquire and release' block instead of using a file handle, code could run without error. But that way is not good as every thread will open the file and close it.

Any explanation why? I am using Python 2.7.3 and Windows 7.

Comment: Did you mean to forget `self.` in the line `fp.write()`? If `fp` is a global, it could end up being closed..

Comment: sorry, it's a typo. Correct the question. I passed a file handle into the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added below code to to the end of the code to wait all child threads to finish and then close the file. And now it works.

```
  while threading.activeCount() >1:
      pass
  else:
      print 'All done!'
      f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be main thread is dead before `write` is called? I have tried your code with this addition at the end of script:

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

And it works.

Comment: but i did not use `thread.daemon=True`. So you mean that if main thread is dead, the file would close even though the sub-thread is still running? If so, I think `thread.join()` would be better. But this would slow the execution speed.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly this. If you set `thread.daemon=True` for this threads it will work, I think.