# Parse input file to thread in flask

Tags: multithreading, flask, amazon-s3, request

I have a web application where I want to upload files from the user to an S3 bucket. To achieve this I want the upload process to take place in a separate thread so I can properly start a loading animation. But whenever I parse the file to the thread I get the error:

> I/O operation on closed file

This is the code where I get the file, parse it to the thread and start it.

```
#Dashboard from which I can upload the file
@application.route('/dashboard', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard_post():
    file = request.form.get('input_file')
    worker_thread = Thread(target=upload_file, args=[file])
    worker_thread.start()

    return redirect(url_for('dashboard_upload'))


#Thread function
def upload_file(file):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    try:
        S3_CLIENT.upload_fileobj(
            file,
            <bucketname>,
            filename,
        )

    except Exception as e:
        print("Something Happened: ", e)
```

What do I have to change to be able to parse the file? I don't want to save the file on the host machine to upload it from there because the files can get pretty big.

Comment: maybe you need to lock the file, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525833/python-error-i-o-operation-on-closed-file-when-using-a-file-handle-with-thread)

Comment: the file is probably closed after the dashboard_post function runs

Comment: But when I wait for the file to be uploaded I can just delete the thread instead and do it in my main thread. Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, why don't you just try it :))